# Integrating x,y gaussian distribution over a square area, expressed in terms of error (erf)

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, parameter-estimation, error-function

I am struggling to wrap my head around the math of a paper I need to understand for my work. In essence, it has to do with super-resolution microscopy, and determining the expected value of a pixel in a detector given a sub-pixel source of light that is scattered according to a (simplified) 2D gaussian distribution around the "true" source emitter.

Specifically, the part I am struggling with understanding the steps between the expression as an integral over the (unit square) area centered on (x,y) (Eq.2), and the error function/erf expression equivalent it is converted to (Eq.3/4a/4b). Attached is the relevant area of the paper supplemental.

Any and all help, or pointers on where to look or what to try would be greatly appreciated!

[Partial page containing relevant information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm4IU.png)

Equations:

Eq.1: PSF(x,y) = (1/(2 π σ^2)) e^(-(x - θ_x)^2 - (y - θ_y)^2)/(2σ^2)

... where θ_x,y is the position of the emitter

Eq.2: μ_k(x,y) = θ_I0 * INTEGRAL over A_k [PSF(u,v) du dv] + θ_bg

...where μ_k(x,y) denotes expected value in the kth pixel, θ_I0 is expected photon count, θ_bg is expected background count, and the integral is over the finite area A_k of the kth pixel centered on (x,y)

Eq.3: μ_k(x,y) = θ_I0 * ΔE_x(x,y) * ΔE_y(x,y) + θ_bg

Eq.4.1: ΔE_x(x,y) ≡ 1/2 erf((x - θ_x + 1/2)/(2 σ^2)) - 1/2 erf((x - θ_x + 1/2)/(2 σ^2))
Eq.4.2: ΔE_y(x,y) ≡ 1/2 erf((y - θ_y + 1/2)/(2 σ^2)) - 1/2 erf((y - θ_y + 1/2)/(2 σ^2))

The Gaussian standard deviation, σ, is experimentally determined.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com) is propably the better forum for your question.

Comment: I'll repost on physics.stackexchange then, thanks! :)